# What is the expected behavior for epoll_wait-ing on the read end of a closed pipe?

Tags: c, linux, epoll

I am having trouble understanding this from the epoll documentation: Say I have `pipe(fd)` so we have `fd[0]` for reading and `fd[1]` for writing. We write some stuff to `fd[1]` and then close it:

```
write(fd[1], "abc", 3);
write(fd[1], "def", 3);
close(fd[1]);
```

Potentially simultaneously, we create an epoll instance, tell it to wait until it can read from `fd[0]`, and read 3 bytes once it does.

```
int epoll_fd = epoll_create(10);
struct epoll_event ev;
ev.events = EPOLLIN;
ev.data.fd = fd[0];
epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, fd[0], &ev);

struct epoll_event event;
epoll_wait(epoll_fd, &event, 1, -1);
char buffer[100];
read(fd[0], buffer, 3);
```

Now we call `epoll_wait` again. Even though pipe is closed, the kernel should still have 3 bytes buffered for us available to be read from `fd[0]`, yes? So I'd expect the following to work (ie, not block):

```
epoll_wait(epoll_fd, &event, 1, -1);
read(fd[0], buffer, 3);  // buffer should start with "def" now
```

Now there's nothing left in the pipe and the write end is closed. What should happen if I `epoll_wait` a third time?

```
epoll_wait(epoll_fd, &event, 1, -1);  // will this block indefinitely?
read(fd[0], buffer, 3);
```

I have two different pieces of code both seeming to indicate different answers here, so I'd like to know what *should* be happening to better decipher what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the write end of a pipe being closed should be signaled with read() returning 0.

Assuming:

- You're not using epoll edge trigger
- You have checked all calls for errors.
- The write end really is closed 
  (i.e. there's no leaked descriptor from e.g. a 
  dup() call or fork())

then your last epoll_wait should not block, and the following read() should return 0.

(And remember to check that read() returns the amount of bytes you assume it returns)

Comment: Re: `fork()` Ah thank you so much! That's indeed what was causing the issue in the version where `epoll_wait` seemed to be blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this line of your post:

```
epoll_wait(epoll_fd, &event, 1, -1);  // will this block indefinitely?
```

the ***maxevents*** argument is set to `1`, so you should see up to only one event regardless, but that has litte to do with your question, really.
the ***timeout*** argument is set to `-1`, this will cause `epoll_wait()` to ***block indefinitely***

if you do not want it to block, or pass some finite amount of time, then pass 0 for timeout, this will cause `epoll_wait()`  to return immediately, even if there are no events.

Comment: epoll_wait should not block indefinitely if there are events pending.

Comment: @nos _if_ events, but -  ***[according to this:](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_wait.2.html)*** _Specifying a
       timeout of -1 causes epoll_wait() to block indefinitely, while
       specifying a timeout equal to zero cause epoll_wait() to return
       immediately, even if no events are available._

Comment: @ryker it causes it to wait indefinitely for an event, as opposed to wait a specific amount of time for an event. Blocking indefinitely, never to wake up again ever would be a rather useless thing to do.

Comment: @nos - Yes, thanks for your persistence.  I re-read my source link after your first response, and saw the error of my conclusion.  Good answer BTW, +1.